# Maybe image can be enlarged when you click on it?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Referring to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33149/opensuse-11-4-very-slow-on-8-gb-ram-i5-processor?rq=1), I had to copy the url of first two images and open it separately in a browser to view it, so maybe there could be something like lightbox use to open these image in original size ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to make images links (instead of `![Top with "M"][1]`, you use `[![Top with "M"][1]][1]`), but can't you just open the image in a new tab?

[image: Open Image in New Tab]

It's one extra click, and doesn't block the rest of the page